# Convert a jQuery set into HTML

Tags: jquery

Given a jQuery result set, how do you convert that back into plain HTML?

```
<div class="abc">
    foo <strong>FOO</strong>
</div>
<div class="def">
    bar
</div>
```

--

```
var $mySet = $('div');
```

Given `$mySet`, how would you go about returning to the plain HTML above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your set consists of precisely one item, you can use ye olde Javascript:

```
var html = $mySet[0].outerHTML; // note HTML is all caps... that always burns me
```

Comment: You could extend this to get all of the elements fairly easily: `$mySet.map(function () { return this.outerHTML; }).get().join('');` Back when I wrote this question, not all browsers supported `outerHTML`, but now it appears to have [pretty good support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: it will only return the HTML string of the first element found.

Comment: Not a big fan of this answer -- what if your set _doesn't_ consist of one item?

Comment: 5 cent why this answer is very bad: [https://jsfiddle.net/h3c9hcp7/](https://jsfiddle.net/h3c9hcp7/) - if you update e.g. input's value and afterwards try `outerHTML` it won't print it, you will simply lose your value

Answer (score 11):

i'd suggest creating a temporary container, then grabbing the `html()` of that new container:

```
var html = $('<div>').append( $('div').clone() ).html();
alert(html);

// alerts:

<div class="abc">
    foo <strong>FOO</strong>
</div><div class="def">
    bar
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe what you want is a client-side templating engine.
check out the post [Client Templating with jQuery](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/509108.aspx)

i'm using it and it's pretty cool.
You just set the template you want to use inside a div, then you feed it with a json object/array and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $mySet = $('div');
var html = $mySet.html();
```

If you want the element's HTML as well (untested):

```
var $mySet = $('div');
var html = $mySet.clone().wrap('<div></div>').html();
```

By the way, here $ is part of the variable name.  Javascript doesn't require a $ like in PHP for variable names, but it doesn't hurt to have it.

Comment: that's incorrect sorry. this will just return the inner HTML of the first div. i'm actually looking to get it to return to HTML like in the first example above.

Comment: Give my second snippet a try.

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery [appendTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo#selector) method, if I understand well what you mean by "returning to the plain HTML above".