# How to Convert an array of jQuery Objects to an HTML String

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the jQuery Infinite Carousel, it uses `.clone()` to do the infinite effect.  This works great unless the code it's cloning has HTML5 Elements.  IE7 and IE8 have trouble applying HTML5 Element-specific CSS rules to cloned or otherwise post-page-load inserted elements.

The [innerShiv](http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/) JavaScript plugin inserts the elements in a way that IE7 and IE8 will render just fine with the appropriate CSS.

The problem is that innerShiv takes an HTML string as a parameter, but the jQuery .clone() method returns an array of jQuery objects.

In order to use the two together, I need to convert the output from .clone() into an HTML string that innerShiv will be able to parse.

Any thoughts on how this could be done?

Comment: just call [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on the objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML:

```
<p class="foo"><canvas class="bar"></canvas></p>
```

JavaScript: <sup>[[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325087/convert-a-jquery-set-into-html/325152#325152)]</sup>

```
// grab the object, with HTML 5 element(s).
var p = $('p');

// clone it
var c = p.clone();

// grab the inner html (wrap it so we can get the HTML)
var html = $('<div>').append(c).html();

// alert us of the contents
alert(html);
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/tDFYn/

Answer (score 1):

Use `.clone().html();`, it will convert the objects to a string.
Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/9k2LS/

-edit-

Reconsidered: Indeed @Jazzerus, why use .clone()? .html() without clone() will do.

Comment: `.html()` without `.clone()` won't technically do as `.clone` duplicates the current object and ancestors. `.html()` is only the code for the ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = $.parseHTML(yourHtmlString); //Returns an Array of HTML Objects

//some operations on html like $(html).find() ...

html  = $('<div>').append(html).html();  // Returns string (string of html)
console.log(html);
```

Comment: You should consider adding an explanation of the solution you're proposing.